# Why does my ASP.NET MVC 4 application create new entities instead of updating the old ones?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

**EDIT**: The solution I selected probably wasn't the best, but it definitely worked. I'll be going through my code over the next week (once this project is done) and I'll update my question when I understand what went wrong.

I'm using the ASP.NET MVC 4 framework with Entity 5. Here's some code:

The class to be instantiated and saved (fresh) in the database:

```
    public class ClassCancellation
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Faculty Professor { get; set; }
        public DateTime CancelledOn { get; set; }
        public Course Course { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public ClassDate ClassCancelled { get; set; }
        public Message CancellationMessage { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
```

It's mapped from the viewmodel called `CancellationFull` (with AutoMapper):

```
public class CancellationForList
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public CourseForList Course { get; set; }
    public ClassDateForList ClassCancelled { get; set; }
}

public class CancellationFull : CancellationForList
{
    public CancellationFull()
    {
        this.Students = new List<StudentForList>();
    }
    public FacultyForList Professor { get; set; }
    public MessageForList CancellationMessage { get; set; }
    public DateTime CancelledOn { get; set; }
    public List<StudentForList> Students { get; set; }
}
```

This is the repo method that turns a `CancellationFull` into a `ClassCancellation` and then saves it to the database:

```
    public CancellationFull createClassCancellation(CancellationFull c) 
    {
        ClassCancellation newCancellation = Mapper.Map<ClassCancellation>(c);

        dc.ClassCancellations.Add(newCancellation);
        dc.SaveChanges();

        return Mapper.Map<CancellationFull>(dc.ClassCancellations.FirstOrDefault(cc => cc.Id == newCancellation.Id));
    }
```

Why, for the love of god why, does the database create new objects for `Faculty` and `Course` when the `Id` (primary key) of each's existing entity counterpart is provided? It might also be doing the same with `Student` objects but I haven't looked that closely.

Before the `ClassCancellation` instance is saved to the database the debugger shows that it's attributes `Professor` of type `Faculty` and `Course` of type `Course` have the correct primary key - that is, the primary key of the already existing entities of those types that I'm trying to update with a reference to the new `ClassCancellation` object.

Driving me nuts. Feel free to ask for clarification!

EDIT:

Here's the logic where the `CancellationFull` viewmodel is constructed from form data and viewmodels about existing objects retrieved from their respective repos:

```
     newCancellation = new CancellationFull();
     newCancellation.CancelledOn = DateTime.Now;
     newCancellation.ClassCancelled = repoClass.getClassDateForListById(Int32.Parse(classIds[i]));
     newCancellation.Course = repoCourse.getForList(newCancellation.ClassCancelled.Course.Id);
     newCancellation.CancellationMessage = repoMessage.getMessageForList(newMessage.Id);
     newCancellation.Professor = repoFac.getFacultyForList((int)Session["facId"]);

     var students = repoStudent.getStudentsForListByCourse(newCancellation.Course.Id);

     foreach ( var student in students )
     {
         newCancellation.Students.Add(student);
     }

     repoCancellation.createClassCancellation(newCancellation);
```

Here's an example of one of those repo methods (the rest are very similar):

```
    public CourseForList getForList(int? id)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<CourseForList>(dc.Courses.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id));
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks John. I'm new to this ^.^

Comment: Where do those faculty and course objects come from? Are they attached yet?

Comment: The faculty and course objects are retrieved from the database and then mapped to viewmodels in other repo methods.

EDIT: tried to clarify a bit -.-

Comment: Doesn't Mapper.Map create a brand new object with some of the DBs properties, but without the necessary EF properties that tell it already exists in the DB? Hence why it keeps adding new ones.

Comment: Tom: I was wondering if that might be the case... Seems to make AutoMapper rather useless though doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I find the easiest solution is when updating a model, clear any related entities, then re add them.

ie:

```
 newCancellation.Students.Clear();

 foreach ( var student in students )
 {
     newCancellation.Students.Add(student);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Attach()` instead of `Add()`

```
dc.ClassCancellations.Attach(newCancellation);
dc.SaveChanges();
```

`Add()` is used for new objects that do not already exist in the database. `Attach()` is used for creating relationships to entities that already exist in the database.

**EDIT**

Without seeing your code, the best solution I can recommend to attach is to create a 'stub' instance and then attach that to your `newCancellation`:

```
var existingCourse = new Course{ Id = newCancellation.ClassCancelled.Course.Id };
db.Courses.Attach(existingCourse);
newCancellation.Course = existingCourse;
```

Comment: The `newCancellation` object is brand new and needs to be saved. Some of its attributes reference objects that already exist in the database.

Comment: Thanks for bringing `Attach()` to my attention - it may help me with another issue I've been having.

Comment: Can you show where the Faculty and Course objects are set?

Comment: They are created when initially seeding the database through the entity `dbcontext`. I'll add the code where they are retrieved in viewmodel form.

Comment: Heh, unless you really think it would be helpful. I'll paste the whole thing, but this page will get reeaaaallly long :P

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have multiple contexts, or units of work. When you add the newCancellation to the dc context, it also adds any related entity in the object graph that is not tracked in the dc context. I think your best option is:

```
dc.ClassCancellations.Add(newCancellation);
dc.Entry(newCancellation.Course).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
dc.Entry(newCancellation.Faculty).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

See [Julie Lerman's article on this issue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx) for an explanation and other options.

In my opinion, EF should recognize entities that have autonumbered keys and not insert them if the key is assigned.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It throws an exception (`InvalidOperationException`) stating that _Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'IntAssignment.Models.Faculty' have the same primary key value._